# cart icon is not showing properly

Tags: html, css

hello i am new in website developer and i am create product list. at left top corner i am showing wishlist icon same as i want display cart icon at top-right corner in same css effect of wishlist. what is changes done in css? so my cart icon is get position top-right corner of product. I uses same css of wishlist but it is hidden on hover effect..

html:

```
  <div class="ps-shoe mb-30">
    <div class="ps-shoe__thumbnail">
    <a class="ps-shoe__cart" href="#">
    <i class="ps-icon-cart"></i></a>
    <a class="ps-shoe__favorite" href="#">
    <i class="ps-icon-heart"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

css of wishlist:

```
 .ps-shoe .ps-shoe__favorite {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 10000;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
    transform: scale(0, 0); }
    .ps-shoe .ps-shoe__favorite i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      color: #fff; }
    .ps-shoe .ps-shoe__favorite.active, .ps-shoe .ps-shoe__favorite:hover {
      background-color: #e68700; }
```

i am apply same css effect on ps-shoe__cart but it is hide.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing showing on your page at the moment, because you are having

```
transform: scale(0, 0); }
```

Which basically set your width and height to 0. Not sure what you are trying to do here?

I suggest you have a read at what you have in your CSS block and try to understand everything :)